# Identifying Location of Error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am relatively new to Python, and I am attempting to follow a tutorial on how to build a web application. All my code checks out, however, when I attempt to access the app via localhost, I get the following error: **"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable."** I'm not sure what the error is referring to in my code, and I would appreciate any pointers as to how to identify and resolve this error.

Code:

**Service.py**

```
from models import ToDoModel


class ToDoService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = ToDoModel()

    def create(self, params):
        self.model.create(params["Title"], params["Description"])
```

**models.py**

```
import _sqlite3

class Schema:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = _sqlite3.connect('todo.db')
        self.create_user_table()
        self.create_to_do_table()
        # Why are we calling user table before to_do table?
        # What happens if we swap them?

    def create_to_do_table(self):
        query = """
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Todo" (
                  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                  Title TEXT,
                  Description TEXT,
                  _is_done boolean,
                  _is_deleted boolean,
                  CreatedOn Date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
                  DueDate Date,
                  UserId INTEGER FOREIGNKEY REFERENCES User(_id)
                );
                """

        self.conn.execute(query)

    def create_user_table(self):
        query = """
               CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "User" (
               _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
               Name TEXT NOT NULL,
               Email TEXT,
               CreatedOn Date default CURRENT_DATE
               );
               """
        self.conn.execute(query)


class ToDoModel:
    TABLENAME = "TODO"

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = _sqlite3.connect('todo.db')

    def create(self, Title, description):
        query = f'insert into {self.TABLENAME} ' \
                f'(Title, Description) ' \
                f'values ("{Title}","{description}")'

        result = self.conn.execute(query)
        return result
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

from Service import ToDoService
from models import Schema

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/todo", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def create_todo():
    return jsonify(ToDoService().create(request.get_json()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Schema()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/micahwilcox/PycharmProjects/todo-flask/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/micahwilcox/PycharmProjects/todo-flask/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/micahwilcox/PycharmProjects/todo-flask/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/micahwilcox/PycharmProjects/todo-flask/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/micahwilcox/PycharmProjects/todo-flask/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/micahwilcox/PycharmProjects/todo-flask/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/micahwilcox/PycharmProjects/todo-flask/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/micahwilcox/PycharmProjects/todo-flask/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/micahwilcox/PycharmProjects/todo-flask/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/micahwilcox/PycharmProjects/todo-flask/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/micahwilcox/PycharmProjects/todo-flask/app.py", line 10, in create_todo
    return jsonify(ToDoService().create(request.get_json()))
  File "/Users/micahwilcox/PycharmProjects/todo-flask/Service.py", line 10, in create
    ToDoModel().create(params["Title"], params["Description"])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I am interfacing with the program using Python Shell with the following code:

```
requests.post("http://localhost:5000/todo", 
                  json={"Title":"my first todo", 
                        "Description":"my first todo"})

requests.get("http://localhost:5000/todo", 
                      json={"Title":"my first todo", 
                            "Description":"my first todo"})
```

The error comes when I attempt to go to localhost:5000/todo on my browser.

Thanks in advance for any help I receive.

Comment: find out what `request.get_json()` is

Comment: Are you 100% sure that that's the exact `requests.post()` call that triggered the error?

Comment: The error comes when I attempt to go to localhost:5000/todo on my browser

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment:

> The error comes when I attempt to go to localhost:5000/todo on my browser

The error happens when your browser calls the endpoint with a GET request with no body. Then `request.get_json()` method will return `None`, and thus `params` is `None` and you're trying to do `None["Title"]` which is obviously an error.

Comment: That makes sense. How do I attach a body?

Comment: You are already correctly doing that with the `json` argument to `requests.post/get`, which adds a body to the request and sets the required `Content-type: application/json` header. But there is no way to just make the browser add a JSON body when you navigate to a URL. You should also design your API so that GET calls are indempotent and do not mutate the state of the application.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help! Feel free to [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/510616) if you feel like it was helpful :)